# Css clip-path only in padding-box

Tags: html, css, qtstylesheets

Well with the following image:

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
        img{
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0.5px 0.5px 0 blue)
                drop-shadow(-0.5px 0.5px 0 blue)
                drop-shadow(0.5px -0.5px 0 blue)
                drop-shadow(-0.5px -0.5px 0 blue);

        filter: drop-shadow(0.5px 0.5px 0 blue)
                drop-shadow(-0.5px 0.5px 0 blue)
                drop-shadow(0.5px -0.5px 0 blue)
                drop-shadow(-0.5px -0.5px 0 blue);
        }
        </style>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzeFd.png" width="25px" height="25px" style="width:25px;height:25px;clip-path: polygon(-5px -5px,15px 0px,15px 30px,-5px 30px);" />
        <!--clip-path: padding-box polygon(0px 0px,15px 0px,15px 20px,0px 20px)-->
    </body>
</html>
```

how we can allow filter to fill the rest of the star?

I want this for vote purposes (example: mean value:5.2/10 --> 5 stars and 20% of 1 star).

I don't want a `<svg>` solution because i want to use the css code in pyqt5 python app.

Comment: Just remove the clip path.

Comment: @AHaworth doesn't solve the problem because i want the yellow part of the star to be filled percent (example 20%).

Comment: I dont think I'm understanding the problem Your star is filled 20%. Are you asking for what would be the Javascript to do this? I would use CSS variables to set the amount of the final star that was to be shown. Can you show us the JS you are using to set up the stars?